# How do i create a loop that implement a recursive binary search to search for n numbers in a array? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, recursion, binary-search

My code only print one number, how can i create a loop to search n numbers?

```
package binariarecursiva;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class BinariaRecursiva {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  int[] array = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 19, 21, 27, 31, 35, 45, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 89, 95, 101, 200, 501, 707, 1000};
  Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = teclado.nextInt();
  int x = teclado.nextInt();
  int esquerda = 0;
  int direita = array.length-1;
  System.out.println(buscaBinaria(array,  esquerda,  direita, x, n));
}

public static int buscaBinaria (int[] array, int esquerda, int direita, int x, int n)
{
    int meio = (esquerda + direita)/2; 
    if(direita < esquerda)
    {
        return -1; 
    }

    if(x==array[meio])
    {
        return meio; 
    }
    else if(x<array[meio])
    {
       return buscaBinaria(array, esquerda, meio - 1, x);
    }
    else
    {
        return buscaBinaria(array, meio + 1, direita, x);          
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem? And maybe you want to paste the code in English since this it this platforms language and people could understand it more easily, which will lead to more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your `main()` method a bit. First you read the value for n from user input as you already did. Then you loop n times and on each iteration you ask the user what kind of value he would like to search for.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 19, 21, 27, 31, 35, 45, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 89, 95, 101, 200, 501, 707, 1000};
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of runs: ");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    int esquerda = 0;
    int direita = array.length-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter number to search for: ");
        int x = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(buscaBinaria(array, esquerda, direita, x));
    }
}
```

Also change the signature of `buscaBinaria()`, it does not need the n as a parameter.

Full code

```
package binariarecursiva;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinariaRecursiva {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] array = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 19, 21, 27, 31, 35, 45, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 89, 95, 101, 200, 501, 707, 1000};
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of runs: ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();
        int esquerda = 0;
        int direita = array.length-1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number to search for: ");
            int x = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.println(buscaBinaria(array, esquerda, direita, x));
        }
    }

    public static int buscaBinaria (int[] array, int esquerda, int direita, int x)
    {
        int meio = (esquerda + direita)/2;
        if(direita < esquerda)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if(x==array[meio])
        {
            return meio;
        }
        else if(x<array[meio])
        {
            return buscaBinaria(array, esquerda, meio - 1, x);
        }
        else
        {
            return buscaBinaria(array, meio + 1, direita, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just that simple! That will work for me! Thanks a lot! :)